# ng-content and textarea compatibility issue

Tags: html, angular

I have a custom `my-textarea` component with the following template:

```
<textarea>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</textarea>
```

When I test the component and try to inject some text in it (as we do with a normal `textarea` html element):

```
<my-textarea>some text</my-textarea>
```

I get an empty component without the expected injected string, `some text`.
Any idea why could this be happening? I tried to do the same thing with a button and it works. (`<button><ng-content></ng-content></button>`).
Is there a compatibility issue between `ng-content` and `textarea`?
Thanks

Comment: Oooops same issue one year after :(

Comment: I am surprised this is not considered a bug!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @Input() annotation in your component.ts

For example:

```
@Input() someText: string;
```

And now you can "inject" the text you want in the component like:

```
<my-textarea [someText]="'sometext'"></my-textarea>
```

Or when you have the text in a variable in another component

```
<my-textarea [someText]="someVariableWithText"></my-textarea>
```

## edit

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
   text:string = "textToINsertINAnothercomponent";
}
```

app.component.html

```
<my-textarea [textInCustom]="text"></my-textarea>
```

my-texarea.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: "my-textarea",
    templateUrl: "app/my-textarea/my-textarea.component.html"
})
export class ReviewList {
    @Input() textInCustom: string;
}
```

my-textarea.component.html:

```
<text-area>{{textInCustom}}</text-area>
```

Comment: Yes thanks. I thought of this solution. But I wanted to make my custom component behave exactly as a normal `textarea`. That's why I was looking if we can make `ng-content` work as expected with the custom component. That was the purpose of the question.

Comment: You can surely make a custom component which contains a text-area which contains the variable "someText" that's possible with the given code above. So I dont understand what you mean? Edited above

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I am looking for a way that adds the text of the textarea like this: `<my-textarea>some text</my-textarea>`.
Normally we should be able to do this if we use ng-content in the template of the custom comonent (`<textarea><ng-content></ngcontent></textarea>`). But it's not working and I'm looking for a way to make it work with `ng-content`.
I don't want to use the solution of the input that you suggested above.